# Laravel defining a many-to-many relationship with the same table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, laravel-5.6

So I have a `posts` table with a corresponding `Post` model. I want to have related posts for every post. Since a post can have many other related posts, it is a many-to-many relationship between the `posts` table and the `posts` table (same table).

So I created a `related_posts` pivot table with its corresponding model `RelatedPost`. I want to define this relationship in the two models. Like so:

**Post** model:

```
public function related()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany(RelatedPost::class, 'related_posts', 'related_id', 'post_id');
}
```

**RelatedPost** model:

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'related_posts', 'post_id', 'related_id');
}
```

Now in my post controller after selecting a particular post, I want to get all its related posts. So I do this:

```
$post->related()->get();
```

But when I do this I get the following error message:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'related_posts' (SQL: select `related_posts`.*, `related_posts`.`related_id` as `pivot_related_id`, `related_posts`.`post_id` as `pivot_post_id` from `related_posts` inner join `related_posts` on `related_posts`.`id` = `related_posts`.`post_id` where `related_posts`.`related_id` = 1) "

This is my migration for the pivot table:

```
  Schema::create('related_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->unsignedInteger('post_id');
      $table->unsignedInteger('related_id');
      $table->timestamps();

      $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
      $table->foreign('related_id')->references('id')->('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
  });
```

I have searched all over everywhere and though the solutions I've found really make sense I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you creating `RelatedPost` model? You don't need it for your intermediate table. Your `related()` relation makes no sense - it should be pointing to `Post` model via `related_posts` table.

Comment: @d3jn Thanks a lot mate. It's working now. You have saved me hours!

Comment: @AwaMelvine can you add your answer here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Thanks to @d3jn's comment on my question I was able to solve my problem. So I am posting the solution here just in case someone else might need it.

I am relating the `Post` model to itself not to the pivot model `RelatedPost`. So I don't need a `RelatedPost` model. I only need a pivot table (`related_post`), and the relation's `id`s namely `related_id` and `post_id`.

So with my migration unchanged, I only need to do away with the `RelatedPost` model and change my `related()` method in the `Post` model to look like this:

```
public function related()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'related_posts', 'post_id', 'related_id');
}
```

And now everything works.